# "From which" vs "of which" vs "by which"

Tags: meaning, grammaticality, prepositions, word-usage

I came across this sentence while reading an article:

> Four people were killed after a BMW from which they were traveling rammed into a truck.

My questions are:

1. Is "from which" correct in this sentence and why?
2. If "from which" is replaced by "in which" and "by which", are they also correct?

Answer (score 2):

I would use "in which"

> Four people were killed after a BMW **in which** they were traveling,
> rammed into a truck.

Or I wouldn't use "which" at all and rephrase the sentence in this way

> Four people were killed after **the** BMW they were traveling **in**
> rammed into a truck.